# MakeScreenshot for dynamically created control

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I need to **dynamically** draw created control to bitmap.

But it does not work, it does not draw anything.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  cb: TCheckBox;
  BMP: TBitmap;
begin
  BMP:= nil;

  cb:= TCheckBox.Create(nil);
  try
    cb.IsChecked:= true;
    cb.Repaint;
    BMP:= cb.MakeScreenshot;
    BMP.SaveToFile('C:\bmp.bmp');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(cb);
    FreeAndNil(BMP);
  end;
end;
```

I have tried also directly `PaintTo` - but the same effect. I have tried also setting `parent` but this is still not enough.

If i do same for control placed by hand on the form it is working, but dynamically created not.

How to do this. This control should not be visible anywhere i need to paint it only and free it.

Comment: I am really interested why someone vote against this question? It is not clear? It do not show my effort? Or what?

Comment: Have you tried adding a parent to your checkbox?

Comment: My suggestion is that your `TCheckBox` should be visible before making screenshot. I'm doubting that control stores its visual appearance inside of itself on internal bitmap and ready to deliver it on demand. And also wrap bitmap creating in separate `try...finally`.

Comment: @Dima `TCheckBox` is visible by default when creating new.  No need for an additional `try/finally` around the BMP - it is initialized to `nil`, so the existing `Free` will take care of the generated object in `MakeScreenShot` if it is successfully created but subsequent calls in the `try` fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues.  First, you do need the control to be parented for it to be paintable.

Second, you're saving as a BMP which does not support the transparency used in FMX to generate the screenshot (and is platform specific besides).  Save it as a PNG instead.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  cb: TCheckBox;
  BMP: TBitmap;
begin
  BMP:= nil;
  cb:= TCheckBox.Create(nil);
  try
    cb.Parent := self;
    cb.Text := 'testing';      
    cb.IsChecked:= true;
    bmp := cb.MakeScreenshot;
    BMP.SaveToFile('C:\bmp.png');
  finally
    cb.Free;
    BMP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Interesting detail though, if you omit the `Text` assignment, the whole cb image is totally black. If you assign just a space or any other text, it shows up as expected.

Comment: Yes, the problem was `TEXT`. If ommited, checkbox was not draw at all. Thank you.